# Load Image from local private directory in a webview

Tags: android, android-webview

*Context :*

My app sometimes displays "Sheets" which are html files that contain texts and images :

```
<p>image description </p>
<p><img src="/api/medias/get/videos/56afad6447eba61c8099544b?thumbnail=true&amp;company=4f86d0a9d655ab9794f5d1d2&amp;fullSizedCover=true" 
    alt="" 
    data-id="56afad6447eba61c8099544b" 
    data-type="video" data-width="640" data-height="1136" /></p>
```

Then I use `body.loadDataWithBaseURL(<my api url>, body, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, null);`

I don't think it's relevant but I'll say it just in case, I have a template body that contains css and javascript. the js script detect images click and transmit the "data-id" to an android method (via a `JavascriptInterface`). In this case it opens a video player and plays it.

---

*Problem :*

My app allow the user to download these Sheets for latter offline vizualisation. So I download the html, then download the images to my local private directory (`Context.getFileDir()`) and change the src of the html to set the "thumbnail" sources to the images I downloaded :

```
<p>video</p>
<p><img src="69c623955ecb5bd414f908cd383f3809.jpg" 
    alt="" 
    data-id="56afad6447eba61c8099544b" 
    data-type="video" data-width="640" data-height="360" /></p>
```

My question is : What do I put as base url to my webview for me to get the expected behaviour (ie : display the downloaded images).

I tried `Context.getFileDir().getAbsolutePath()`, `content://com.android.htmlfileprovider` and some other.

Should I do differently ?

Thank a lot,

---

This works well:

`Picasso.with(iv.getContext()).load(new File(getContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + "69c623955ecb5bd414f908cd383f3809.jpg")).into(iv);`

The html :

```
<p>video</p>
<p><img src="69c623955ecb5bd414f908cd383f3809.jpg" alt="" data-id="56afad6447eba61c8099544b" data-type="video" data-width="640" data-height="360" /></p>
```

my base url : `baseUrl = Uri.fromFile(getContext().getFilesDir()).toString();`

And finaly : 
`webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, body, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, null);`

Comment: "I tried Context.getFileDir().getAbsolutePath()," -- try that, but with a `file` scheme. Easier to use `Uri.fromFile(getFilesDir()).toString()`.

Comment: My images still don't display with this baseUrl : `file:///data/user/0/<my package>/files`, wheareas `new File(Context.getFilesDir()+"/"+"69c623955ecb5bd414f908cd383f3809.jpg").exists()`==true.

Comment: @CommonsWare also are these useful ? (did not have any before, just added them but it doesn't seem to change anything) : 

        - `body.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`
        - `body.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);`
        - `body.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);`
        - `body.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);`

Comment: I think those are for URLs and stuff in the content itself. It's been ages since I tried loading content from a local file, so I forget the details, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok thank you anyway !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use null baseUrl if you already downloaded/have template, and just pass that html template as a body to webview. 
And before passing find img tags in it and set img src with a full path to locally stored file. Smth like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(newHtml);
Elements elems = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
for (Element el : elems) {
    String filename = el.attr("src"); //presumably only name
    String picUri = "file:///" + folder + "/"+filename;
    el.attr("src", picUri);   
}
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlBody, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: I don't know why but indeed, It doen't work putting the "base" in the base url but passing null and putting it manualy inside the src tags works